# How to find exact row match using IN in Where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, chat

I have two tables  tbl_group AND tbl_members.
Here is snapshot of both the tables.

```
+----+------------+
| id | groupTitle |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Group 1    |
|  2 | Group 2    |
+----+------------+

+----+---------+--------+
| id | groupId | userId |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 |
|  2 |       1 |      2 |
|  3 |       1 |      3 |
|  4 |       2 |      1 |
|  5 |       2 |      2 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Now i want to create one more group with userId 3,2 but before that i want to check that is there any group which has same member 3 and 2 not any other.

i have used IN clause but it does not work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT groupId 
FROM tbl_members 
WHERE userId IN (3,2)
```

It is returning both the group though result would be empty.

Comment: is there any group which has same member 3 and 2?? if it is then what and if not then what??

Comment: if there is any group which has same members then result should be that groupId and if there is no group like this then result should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with an `EXISTS` clause which asserts that `userId` of 2/3 does not already occur for any group.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_members (groupId, userId)
SELECT groupId, userId
FROM (
    SELECT 3 AS groupId, 2 AS userId UNION ALL SELECT 3, 3
) t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_members
                  WHERE userId IN (2, 3)
                  GROUP BY groupId
                  HAVING MIN(userId) <> MAX(userId));
```

You would also have to insert a new record into the `tbl_group` table for the new group.

Comment: Thank you for you time tim but what is purpose of  `HAVING MIN(userId) <> MAX(userId)` ?

Comment: The `EXISTS` subquery is pretty canonical, and you'll find it all over this site.  The `HAVING` clause checks that we find two different values in a group, and, furthermore, the `WHERE` clause therefore would make it mean that we found both 2 and 3 in that group.

Comment: I am using MySQL but this query not being properly parsed. `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_members WHERE userId IN (2, 3) GROUP BY grou' at line 2`

Comment: I don't know why there was an error.  I have updated my answer with something else you may try if you are interested.

Comment: sure let me try this!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT groupId FROM tbl_members WHERE userId = '2'
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT groupId FROM tbl_members WHERE userId = '3'
```

Comment: This seems rather impractical

Comment: This answer came in low quality post. Add some explanation even though code is self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use conditional aggregation based filtering using `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` clause. We will use a query to get the `groupId` value which has `userId` values of 3 and 2 only. If the query does not return any such value; this implies that no such Group exists; hence you can create the group.

```
SELECT
  groupId
FROM tbl_members 
GROUP BY groupId
HAVING SUM(userId = 2) AND /* userID 2 exists */
       SUM(userId = 3) AND /* userID 3 exists */
       NOT SUM(userId NOT IN (2,3)) /* No other userId exists (other than 2,3) */
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns groupId's where only 2 AND 3 are in the group. 
Count of all userId's in the group - sum of 1 for records where userId = 2 or 3 has to be 0 if there are no other userid's in the group.

Sure this will work only if 2 and 3 don't repeat itself in the same group.

```
SELECT groupId
FROM tbl_members
GROUP BY groupId
HAVING COUNT(userId)-SUM(userId IN (2,3)) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

First inner query will decide all fetched groups have only two members that will reduce set of unnecessary records then second inner query take that group id and check whether there is no other member then 3,2  in that group, and finally whole query will give group id which has only 3,2 as member.

```
SELECT groupId 
FROM tbl_members m
 WHERE m.userId IN (3,2) AND 
(SELECT COUNT(memberId) FROM tbl_members mmm WHERE mmm.groupId=m.groupId)=2 AND 
(SELECT COUNT(memberId) FROM tbl_members mm WHERE mm.groupId=m.groupId AND 
m.userId NOT IN (3,2))<=0 
GROUP BY groupId
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this query will give the group of values in `userid` (2,3), `groupid` (2,3)
from the table

```
SELECT count(1), userid ,groupid  FROM tbl_members 
WHERE groupid IN (3,2) and userid in (3,2)
group by  userid, groupid;
```